# Infinite loop findSuccessor?

Tags: protocols, p2p, chord

I am currently dealing with the Chord protocol.

For each node there are two functions, `findSuccessor` and `closestPrecedingNode` which are given as pseudo-code.

`findSuccessor` is:

```
n.findSuccessor(id)
  if(id is.in (n, successor])
    return successor;
  else
    n' = closestPrecedingNode(id);
    return n'.findSuccessor(id);
```

`closestPrecedingNode` is:

```
n.closestPrecedingNode(id)
  for i = m downto 1
    if(finger[i] is.in (n, id))
      return finger[i];
  return n;
```

When a node is created, its successor is initially set to the node itself, and its finger table is empty.

Now my question is what happens when there is only one single node, and it is asked for *any* id except its own id. Then `findSuccessor` runs the `else` block and calls `closestPrecedingNode`. Since the finger table is empty, the node itself is returned to `findSuccessor`. Hence `n'` is then equal to `n`.

Afterwards, `findSuccessor` is called on `n'`, which is a recursive call to itself.

And then we have an infinite loop ... or am I missing something?

*NOTE: Pseudo-code is taken from [Chord: A Scalable Peer-to-peer Lookup Protocol
for Internet Applications](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/chord/papers/paper-ton.pdf), page 5.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementer of "jchord" seems to agree with you, since he adds the following code to `findSuccessor`:

```
if (this == successor) {
    return this;
}
```

But there seems to be a more elegant solution with is closer to the pseudo code. When checking if an ID is in the interval (n, successor] (left excluded, right included), make that check cyclic. jDHTUQ seems to do it like this (Starting at line 75. **Warning:** Really ugly code):

http://jdhtuq.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jdhtuq/source_code/distributed_lookup_service/LookupService/src/co/edu/uniquindio/utils/hashing/Key.java?revision=63&view=markup

IMHO performing the interval check in a cyclic way seems to be the right thing to do. The paper you linked says (on page 4):

> The notation (a; b] denotes the segment of the Chord ring obtained by moving clockwise from (but not including) a until reaching (and including) b.

In case of a single node, you would check if

```
id is.in (n, n]
```

which should yield `true` since the id is within the ring that starts right after `n` and ends with `n`.

Comment: That's it, great :-).
So it basically comes down to the question what you define as "included in the interval" ...

Comment: The comparison between `this` and `successor` you mentioned is necessary nevertheless, because the finger table may be initially empty, but the successor may already be set to another node (directly after a join, e.g.). Then the `if` of `findSuccessor` may fail, and then you need that comparison to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: There is no chance of this function going into infinite loop because if there is just one node (k) in the DHT, i.e. node k is it's own successor then any arbitrary ID including it's own will fall in the "clockwise circular interval" (k, k].